# Invalid function warning with a recursive Lisp function

Tags: lisp, emacs23

I'm watching [these tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvnwXHsL8eo&list=PL49807FFA2978EFBF) on Lisp and I've been following along so far. However, when I try to evaluate this function,

```
(defun tailfact (n &optional (intermediate 1))
  (if (= n 1)
    (return-from tailfact intermediate))
  (tailfact (1 - n) (* n intermediate)))

(tailfact 5)
```

I get an `Invalid function` warning (I'm running this in Emacs). Not sure what to make of it, or how to fix it.

Comment: The tutorials are using Common Lisp. So I propose to use Common Lisp. Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp have tons of minor and major differences. Finding out what works and what not during learning is not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidentally wrote a space within the `1-` (which is a function for subtracting 1 from the given number). Remove that space (that is, use `(1- n)` instead of `(1 - n)`) and try again.

Also, Emacs Lisp doesn't have `return-from`. Just say `intermediate` instead of `(return-from tailfact intermediate)`. You do have to move the `tailfact` call within the `if` expression though, as the else clause.

Oh, in my testing, I found another point of difference between Common Lisp and Emacs Lisp: the latter doesn't support a default value for optional arguments, and it always uses `nil`. So here's one way to port your code to elisp:

```
(defun tailfact (n &optional intermediate)
  (let ((intermediate (or intermediate 1)))
    (if (= n 1)
        intermediate
      (tailfact (1- n) (* n intermediate)))))
```

However, let me be the first to agree with Rainer's comment. If you're learning from Common Lisp resources, you really should be using a Common Lisp implementation. I've heard that [SLIME](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/) is an awesome Emacs mode for integrating with major CL implementations, including SBCL (which is probably one of the most commonly-used CL implementations).

Comment: Hmmmmm, that didn't work either. It gave the same error.

Comment: It's exactly as I posted it above, with the fix you suggested.

Comment: I see. I just Googled and saw that elisp doesn't have `return-from`, so I edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: So, just literally change the line `(return-from tailfact intermediate)` to `(intermediate)`?

Comment: No. `intermediate` has no parens around it. Also you need to hoist the whole `tailfact` expression within the `if` expression.